# Read specific column value from a text file using Python

Tags: python, text

I have a text file as following:

```
1  1  2  1  1e8
2  1  2  3  1e5
3  2  3  2  2000
4  2  5  6  1000
5  2  4  3  1e4
6  3  6  4  5000
7  3  5  2  2000
8  3  2  3  5000
9  3  4  5  1e9
10 3  2  3  1e6
```

In my text (which is very larger than this example) the second column is number of layer and the last one is energy in that layer, I want to extract the energy in each layer, For example for the number 2 in the second column, I need energy related to this Layer from the last column, and I want to separate this part of text file

```
3  2  3  2  2000
4  2  5  6  1000
5  2  4  3  1e4
```

How can I do this work in python?

Answer (score 2):

You can grab the layers and energies from the text file like this

```
layers = []
energies = []
with open(file) as f:
    for line in f:
        linesplit = line.strip().split()      # splits by whitespace
        layers.append(int(linesplit[1]))      # 2nd index
        energies.append(float(linesplit[-1])) # last index
```

Edit: if you have a header line (at say, line 1) you can skip it with:

```
header_line = 1  # or whatever it is
with open(file) as f:
    for line_number, line in enumerate(f, 1):
        if line_number <= header_line:
             continue
        linesplit = line.strip().split()      
        layers.append(int(linesplit[1]))      
        energies.append(float(linesplit[-1]))
```

I don't know what your file looks like because you haven't posted the full thing so I can't help you more than this without seeing the whole thing (i.e. on pastebin.com).

One last try:

```
layers = []
energies = []
with open(file) as f:
    for lineno, line in enumerate(f, 1):
        linesplit = line.strip().split()      # splits by whitespace
        if not linesplit:  # empty
            continue
        try:
            layers.append(int(linesplit[1]))      # 2nd inde
        except (TypeError, IndexError):
            print("Skipping line {}: {!r}".format(lineno, line))
            continue
        try:
            energies.append(float(linesplit[-1])) # last index
        except TypeError:
            layers.pop()
            print("Skipping and reverting line {}: {!r}".format(lineno, line)):
```

Comment: Thanks, but for doing this, it gives me this error                                                              layers.append(int(linesplit[1]))    
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Layer'

Comment: I'm guessing thats because you have a heade line in your file along the lines of  `something Layer something something Energy`.Obviously you can't convert `"Layer"` to an int, make sure you skip the header line. I'll edit my post to show you how.

Comment: I got the same error again!!!! It is possible that I send my text file that you can see  what is this exactly? I have energy in 130 layer of CT images, and in this text file, I have number of layers which each layer is a matrix with 128 rows and columns, in here I want to separate the data from each layer, that in the next step, I display this data in images,

Comment: unfortunately my data is very big and I just could paste energy deposited in 3 layer in the below link                                                                                       https://pastebin.com/ejr6uXXL

Comment: Well my code works for the part you pasted. I've added one more possible solution to my answer though. It's not pretty, but it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you create a CSV file in the first place?
So you can seperate each value/column with ';'.
Every new row, you print a new line in that CSV file.

If it is a CSV you can simply use 'split'

```
line.split(';')[column you want]
```

example:

```
line = '1;1;2;1;1e8'
print(line.split(';')[5])

>> 1e8
```

EDIT:
read all lines from a file and put it in an array.
NOTE: this code is not tested and was written quickly. It should show direction you have to go.

```
elements = []
f.open('filename')
lines = f.readlines()
for x, line in lines:
    elemenets.append([])
    for y in range(0,5):
        elements[x].append(line.split()[y])
```

If you already know what line you need, you can simply use:

```
f.open('filename')
lines = f.readlines()
print(lines[index_of_line].split()[index_of_item])
```

Comment: The split method is not really a CSV related method. It would work with the original TXT file.

Comment: Why do you need to make it a csv? Just use normal `str.split()` to split by whitespace.

Comment: in his first example, it wasn't really clear what a new line was and it looked realy messy.
If he indeed uses always the same whitespace, CSV isn't needed and .split works fine :)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but, I do not want to split just one row, I want to split all the data in for example Layer 120, which I can display these data on a image,

Answer (score 1):

Split method without any argument will split string on whitespaces.
a.txt - is data filename.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


with open ('a.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        line.strip() # Removes \n and spaces on the end
        var1, var2, var3, var4, var5 = line.split()
        print(var1, var2, var3, var4, var5)
```

Comment: Thanks, but this script just gives me all of my data, but I just need a part of data for example, all data in Layer 120   for example                                                             1    120     2  1     1e8
2    120     2  3     1e5
3    120     2   4   2000
4    120     5  6  1000
5    120     4  3  1e4